# Using self start logistic and gompertz with only initial weight up to 40 days old

Tags: r

I have used the self start gompertz and logistic functions on my growth data for broiler chickens.
My dillemma is that i have data only for the commercial lifespan of the chickens up to 35days for female(pullets) and up to 41 days for male(cocks) and i used the list function

> out.nls<-nlsList(Scales.Weight~SSgompertz(Scales.Age,a0,b0,b1)|SexOfBirds,data=f_79.grp)
>   This gives me separate model coefficients for each case in SexOfBirds. $ different models.
>   What is the best plots to use to describe the models : My learning data is quite substantial 
>   How do I compare the models with test data and generally show how good the fit is?

Comment: This is related to statistics so you should flag to migrate it to [CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Metrics, I'm not sure I agree.  However, it would be good to have a reproducible example, and to see what you've tried so far. In principle there's nothing wrong with fitting an asymptotic function to data that don't get near the asymptote, but it may make the numerics more unstable/finkcy.

Comment: I have managed to generate both logistic and gompertz models with dummy variables, my problem now is that I have so much training data that all my plots are quite messy and not very clear. All the examples use quite restricted sample sizes where i have several years worth of training data. How would i use the predict function to test my models with dummy variables?